# Python doesn' t update random.choice in (f)-string

Tags: python, string, arraylist, random

my python code looks something like this:

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

mix = [f"lalala {random.choice(numbers)} blablabla {random.choice(letters)}"]

for x in range(1, 15):
    print(random.choice(mix))
```

The problem is that it doesn' t update the `random.choice` inside of the f string.
I have no idea why!

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the f-string are evaluated at the time the f-string is declared; they aren't dynamically re-evaluated each time the f-string is referenced.  Putting the f-string inside a `random.choice()` call doesn't change that; all you're doing is making a choice from a list of one item (the one string with one pre-selected random choice).

If you declare the f-string inside your loop, it will be re-evaluated on each iteration:

```
for x in range(1, 15):
    print(f"lalala {random.choice(numbers)} blablabla {random.choice(letters)}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I 'm a beginner in python. Without you I would never have found this out!